# Windows Handle wait until all references are released

Tags: winapi, ipc, wait, handle

I have multiple processes in an IPC system that I am designing. Each process creates a `FileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` as its own memory area. Also, each process creates two semaphores that manage the `FileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` that it already created.

To describe the problem I have, assume 3 processes:

1. `ProcessA` creates `FileMapping`, `MapViewOfFile` and the two semaphores.
2. `ProcessB` and `ProcessC` do similar to `ProcessA`.
3. `ProcessA` wants to send something to `ProcessB`. It connects to the `FileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` and the two semaphores of `ProcessB` and sends whatever it wanted to send.
4. `ProcessB` wants to reopen its communication. It closes its `FileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` and its two semaphores. It sends closing message to Processes `A` and `C`. When Processes `A` and `C` receive the closing message, they will close handles to `FileMapping`, `MapViewOfFile` and the two semaphores associated with `ProcessB`.
5. `ProcessB` closed all its handles and wants to reopen. When it tries to create `MapViewOfFile` it fails since Processes `A` and `C` have not closed the handles to `ProcessB` yet.

Right now (as a temporary fix), I am letting `ProcessB` sleep for 100ms when it is closing in order to give time for Processes A and C to close their handles to `ProcessB`. However, I want a solution that does not involve sleeping.

Is there a way for `ProcessB` to know when **all references to its handle**s (`FileMapping`, `MapViewOfFile` and the two semaphores) are **released by all other processes?** If there is, how can I wait on it?

Comment: **all references to its handles** what you mean under this ?

Comment: As per Microsoft's documentation, an object is only closed when all references to its handle are closed. When you call `CloseHandle` on an object, it only decrements the count of references to that object. When the references count reaches `0`, the object is closed and you can recreate it. I want to know if there is a way to check the reference count.

Comment: no, what you describe in general words, how you try implement ipc - absolute wrong by design.

Comment: "Wants to reopen" is the problem.  There is never a practical scenario where *that* is useful, a process should initialize its mapping when it starts up and not close it until it terminates.  Synchronizing shared memory access is hard enough as-is, no need to make it worse.  So just don't do it, problem solved.

Comment: @RbMm I appreciate your concern about the design. I am exploring a new design ideas and checking the performance upgrade. That's the point of this project, exploration. Anyway, the design is more complicated than described, I need about 5 pages to describe how it works in detail and it is actually pretty fast and reliable.

Comment: @HansPassant I want my system to be able to open multiple IPCs per process as well as flexibility in the `FileMapping` size. Windows allows sizes in multiples of 4k and in some scenarios, I need to expand the `FileMapping`. The safest way to do so while the process is running is by closing and opening IPC again.

Comment: @HansPassant Moreover, let's assume that I shutdown the process and open it up again. What gaurantee do I have that other processes have closed the handles? None. So how can the process open the handles again?

Comment: There is a lot more to making this kind of communication bullet-proof.  It invariably requires designating a "god" process, one that owns the shared memory and monitors other processes, ensuring that they don't quit without saying goodbye explicitly.  Initiating a controlled shutdown on an unexpected crash.  The kind of problem that is behind the death of middleware in the late 90s.  A practical solution is message queuing.

Comment: @HansPassant I will try publishing my design. I actually have taken care of all these issues. My message passing includes handshaking between the processes for each delivered message. While there is no 'god' process, there is a 'god' shared memory that all processes refer to. When a process sends "goodbye" message, it makes sure everyone else received it before it completely terminates. The intention is to provide completely self-hosted IPC and I am doing so.

Comment: If you want to *send* data from one process to another (as opposed to sharing a view into memory), a (named) pipe is likely a lot more appropriate. Added bonus: You get notified about a process closing their end, even if they do not shutdown cleanly, or deregister in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely no winapi function to do this. You can only try to open a handle to a (named) object and see if it fails with the appropriate reason.

So the simplest workaround is to do what are you trying in a loop with `Sleep(0)` or something similar. You may also add an additional synchronization object for this specific purpose, an auto-reset named event which your `ProcessB` may open and `WaitFor....`.

Comment: Conceptually, this is very useful. To get this straight, you're suggesting that after I close the handles, I try to reopen them until I succeed, when I succeed, it means all other processes have released the handles and thus I am the only one holding them, so closing them again means all references are released. Is this correct?

Comment: Sort of. You can also do vice-versa: call `OpenFileMapping` until it fails - this means that the last handle to it has been closed.

Comment: Thank  you. I will try this out and hopefully it will work.

Comment: I was wondering if you could answer this. If I use `namespaces` for each process in my system, would I be able to force close all handles inside the namespace?

Comment: short anwer: NO. You can't force "close handle". Handles may only be closed conventionally, by a call to `CloseHandle`, or when the process exits.

Comment: Thank you. That saved me a lot of time. I wanted to implement `private namespaces` to check what advantages (other than security) I would get. If this isn't one of them, I will leave them to a later project.